# RavenDB: Any equivalent to SQls DELETE MyTable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)

Tags: ravendb

I have a list of records which shouldn't be in the database, a few hundred in total, due to various bugs going back years. I can delete these in code easily, but is there any way to script the delete, similar to the SQl Server DELETE..WHERE,  so it can be run through the Raven UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `DeleteByIndex` method. You create an ad-hoc index specifying the data to delete.

[Set-based operations](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/set-based-operations)

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. I've got my code to script an index, which ops can then run and delete the offedning records through the Raven ui.

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
  {
            var character = session.Load<Employee>("employee/1");
            session.Delete(character);
            session.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: This only deletes a single document. The OP was asking about deleting a number of documents (aka. a 'set').